# How to create the secret key/value in VSTS to use it on Weebhook in Github

Tags: github, azure-devops, webhooks

I want to trigger a Build in VSTS whenever a push is made to my repository in Github. I see that in settings in my repository in Github you can set up a webhook for VSTS.In fact I had this already working but changed the secret by accident and know I have no idea how to get the secret I have been trying to find it in vsts but not having any luck.

Please any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a CI build definition in VSTS to build the github repo, VSTS will create a webhook for push event in the github repo (as the screen shot you showed).

And if you changed the secret incorrectly by accident, you can **delete the webhook and restore it in VSTS web page**. Detail steps as below:

- **First delete the webhook:**

  In github webhook -> Delete webhook -> Yes, delete webhook.

  [image]
- **Then restore the webhook:**

  In VSTS web page -> edit the CI build definition -> Triggers Tab -> it will detect “The remote repository’s webhooks are missing or incorrect” -> Restore.

  [image]

Now the webhook restored with the correct secret and it can send request successful when push event occur.